# Android ListView problems

Tags: android, listview, cursor

I can't get my ListView work. When i run emulator it doesn't display ListView with data from databse wihich I created.

I would like to insert data to database through EditText and then display data

Main Program

```
package test.test;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class TestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private ListView listview;
private TextView textview;
private Button button;
private EditText edittext;
SQLiteDatabase databas;


//private String[] test = {"abc","abc","abc", "abc", "abc", "abc"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ArrayList<String> test2 = new ArrayList<String>();  

    listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.test);
    textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mm);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.kanp);
    edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textetid);

    databas = (new dbHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Editable ord = edittext.getText();
            String ordDb = ord.toString();

            //String sql =   "INSERT INTO ordlista (ord) " +
            //"VALUES (" + ordDb + ")";
            //databas.rawQuery(sql, null);

            values.put("ord", ordDb);
            long varde = databas.insert("ordlista", null, values);

            String varde2 = Long.toString(varde);
            textview.setText(varde2);


        }
    });
    //#############################TORSDAG###############################



    Cursor c = databas.rawQuery( "select ord from ordlista", null);
    startManagingCursor(c);

    int n = 1;
    while(c.isBeforeFirst() == false){
        String dbVarde = c.getString(n); 
        test2.add(dbVarde);
        c.moveToNext();
        n++;

    }







    ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, test2);
    listview.setAdapter(aa);


    //listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, test));




}



  }
```

Comment: Since listveiw not displaying anything that means test2 which you are passing to arrayadapter is not populated with database strings.confirm that you are querying the database properly and not getting empty cursor.

Comment: arey you getting data in test2...?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a SimpleCursorAdapter and save the overhead of maintaining an ArrayAdapter. Rather than having to populate an ArrayList all the time, you can just create a Cursor against the query when you need it updated and set the ListView's adapter. A SimpleCursorAdapter also has the added benefit of handling the list item's population for you based on the columns you provide.

For example:

```
String[] fieldsFromDB = new String[] {"ord"};
int[] fieldsOnListItem = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
Cursor c = databas.rawQuery("select ord from ordlista", null);

listview.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,c,fieldsFromDB,fieldsOnListItem));
```